# ng-click doesn't work inside script

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

I am using the angular-bootstrap in AngularJS, because I want to use dialogs. In my HTML I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="create.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Welcome!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
</div>
```

The modal dialog shows up, but nothing happen when I click on the "OK" button.
There is also no error in the console. When I create a button and place it outside the script, then it works. But I need to use the button in the modal dialog.

I have created a factory for the modal dialog, because I want to use it in my controller. Here the function what works fine:

```
$scope.createGame = function(data){
   // Open the modal dialog
   ModalFactory.open(); 
}
```

Now the modal dialog shows up and the button "OK" appears. When I click on "OK" nothing happen. This is the function I have created for the "OK" button.

```
$scope.ok = function(data){
    // Close the modal dialog
    alert("Test");
}
```

But the triggering of ng-click in that script what you see above doesn't work...

Comment: Is your `$scope.ok` definition located in modal's controller?

Comment: I have located `$scope` in the controller, there I am using the `$scope` ofcourse. But I didn't use it in the `ModalController`, because it's a factory.

Comment: By default BootstrapUI modals have isolated scope created from `$rootScope` and no controller attached. You need to either provide your scope over there, or create a controller for the modal dialog itself. Take a look at their example: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/docs/demo.js

Comment: Thanks, but I need to call the `open` function in that controller from another controller. I don't know how to do that...

Comment: This is what you mean, but how do I call the function in a controller from another controller? See: http://plnkr.co/edit/QnEEwgV2rra9lXR59xwS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function requires a parameter "data" but you are not passing it.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
```

Either Change your function signature like this,

```
$scope.ok = function(){
    // Close the modal dialog
    alert("Test");
}
```

Or Pass the data.

It's always use a different function name rather than just "ok"

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve the problem. The ng-click inside that script is the problem. But I don't know how to fix that.. Because when I create a button outside the script with the same function, it works.

Comment: where have you defined the controller? if you can create a plunker it will be more helpful

Comment: In the app.js, but here you have an overview: http://plnkr.co/edit/TYFyCwMK1hUUQgwjs6sa